# Why is my Mapbox not rendered properly and the why are the markers displayed off the map?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mapbox

I used Mapbox and Reactmap GL to build a map component and use it on my search/results page. There are two problems that I can't seem to find the solution for. Why is the map not displayed properly and the proportions are off? When I resize the window and bring it back to its original state it looks a little better but still off. The Mapbox information and copyright text is kinda far away from the map itself. The markers on the other hand are at the very bottom of the page and not even on the map. The deployed version can be found here: https://airbnb-smoky-six.vercel.app/search?location=London&startDate=10%2F24%2F2022&endDate=10%2F27%2F2022&noOfGuests=1
Just type in London and a date and click search if you want to test it.

The Map component looks like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactMapGL, {Marker, Popup} from 'react-map-gl';
import { getCenter } from 'geolib';
import searchResults from '../files/searchResults.JSON'


function Map() {

    const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState({});
    //Transform the search result object into the {latitude: 45.634634, longitude: 45.674564}
    const coordinates = searchResults.map(result => ({
        longitude: result.long,
        latitude: result.lat,
    }));
    console.log(coordinates)
    // end of transformation (forEach can't return value, which is why we used map)

    const center = getCenter(coordinates);
    
    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        longitude: center.longitude,
        latitude: center.latitude,
        zoom: 11,
    });

    

 return (
    <div>
        <ReactMapGL
            mapStyle="mapbox://styles/fabiocattolico/cl881o5de000j14s1vzugutij"
            mapboxAccessToken={process.env.mapbox_key}
            {...viewport}
            onMove={evt => setViewport(evt.viewport)}
        >

            {searchResults.map(result => (
                <div key={result.long}>
                    <Marker
                        longitude={result.long}
                        latitude={result.lat}
                        // offsetLeft={-0.2}
                        // offsetTop={-0.1}
                    >
                        <p onClick={() => setSelectedLocation(result)} 
                            className='cursor-pointer text-2xl animate-bounce'
                            aria-label="push-pin"
                            role="img"
                        >
                            
                        </p>
                    </Marker>

                    {/* The pop up that should show when marker is clicked */}
                    {selectedLocation.long === result.long ? (
                        <Popup 
                            onClose={() => setSelectedLocation({})}
                            closeOnClick={true}
                            latitiude={result.lat}
                            longitude={result.long}
                        >
                            {result.title}
                        </Popup>
                    ):(
                        false
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </ReactMapGL>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Map
```

The search component looks like this

```
function Search() {
    const router = useRouter();

  //ES6 destructuring
    const { location, startDate, endDate, noOfGuests} = router.query;
    const formattedStartDate = startDate ? format(new Date(startDate), "MM/dd/yyyy") : "";
    const formattedEndDate = endDate ? format(new Date(endDate), "MM/dd/yyyy") : "";
    const range = `${formattedStartDate} - ${formattedEndDate}`;
    


    return (
    <div>
        <Header
             placeholder= {`${location} | ${formattedStartDate}| ${formattedEndDate} | ${noOfGuests} guests `}
        />
            <main className='flex'>
                <section className='flex-grow pt-14 px-6'>
                    <p className='text-xs '>500+ Stays - {range} - {noOfGuests} guests</p>

                    <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold mb-6 mt-2'>Stays in {location}</h1>

                    <div className='hidden md:inline-flex mb-5 space-x-3 text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap'>
                        <p className='button'>Cancellation Flexibilty</p>
                        <p className='button'>Type of Place</p>
                        <p className='button'>Price</p>
                        <p className='button'>Rooms and Beds</p>
                        <p className='button'>More Filters</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-col'>
                        {searchResults.map(({ key, img, description, location, star, price, total, title, long, lat }) => (
                            <InfoCard 
                                key={key}
                                img= {img}
                                location = {location}
                                title={title}
                                description={description}
                                star={star}
                                price={price}
                                total={total}
                                long={long}
                                lat={lat}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    
                </section>

                <section className='hidden lg:inline-flex'>
                    <Map searchResults={searchResults} />
                </section>
            </main>

        <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search;
```